# Postwork of short movie 'agent 327'

Tags: compositing-nodes

I do not know if my writing matches the nature of the forum.
However, I ask.

I was very impressed with the short movie 'agent 327'.

I wonder if the production crew used Blender for postwork like compositing or color correction.

I know that Blender Composer's performance is slower than major effecting & compositing tools like After Effects.

So I wonder if they used the blender to do all the work for their movies.

If you have any information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you should better ask this here https://cloud.blender.org/p/agent-327/blog/ but I guess it should be done all in blender, as usual.

Comment: Thank your link.